# Prevent VS Code IntelliSense inserting ={} after function name

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Since the last Visual Studio Code update, I've got problems with IntelliSense autocompletion. Generally if I want to set a function as a prop (it's the most common use case of this problem) then instead of inserting just function name VS Code is adding `={}` brackets. So how to get rid of this:

```
const func = () => {}
...
<button
   onClick={func={}}
 />
```

and get something like this:

```
const func = () => {}
...
<button
   onClick={func}
 />
```

To clarify - no new add-ons were installed. It's happening for `js/ts` files when writing in React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to fix this

1. Open VS code.
2. Go to File > Preference > Settings then
3. type: `run code` in the settings search bar
4. Select `Edit in settings.json` to open the `settings.json` file
5. Add the `"javascript.preferences.jsxAttributeCompletionStyle": "none"` line to your `settings.json` file

## Why we do this:

In the `defaultSettings.json` file there is this code snippet:

```
// Preferred style for JSX attribute completions.
//  - auto: Insert `={}` or `=""` after attribute names based on the prop type. 
//  - braces: Insert `={}` after attribute names.
//  - none: Only insert attribute names.
"javascript.preferences.jsxAttributeCompletionStyle": "auto",
```

therefore, the default setting for `jsxAttributeCompletionStyle` is `auto` and by setting it to `"none"` in your `settings.json` file you overwrite that default setting.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we can set `JSX Attribute Completion Style` to `none`.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171609#issuecomment-1387107873