# VSCode adds curly braces on autocomplete

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Whenever VSCode does suggestions and I choose one of those suggestions, it adds "={}" behind any variable I auto-complete.

I recorded a little clip to demonstrate the problem:
[image]

I want it to just autocomplete "album" in this case. Not "album={}".

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75323598/836330

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## How to fix this

1. Open VS code.
2. Go to File > Preference > Settings then
3. type: `run code` in the settings search bar
4. Select `Edit in settings.json` to open the `settings.json` file
5. Add the `"javascript.preferences.jsxAttributeCompletionStyle": "none"` line to your `settings.json` file

## Why we do this:

In the `defaultSettings.json` file there is this code snippet:

```
// Preferred style for JSX attribute completions.
//  - auto: Insert `={}` or `=""` after attribute names based on the prop type. 
//  - braces: Insert `={}` after attribute names.
//  - none: Only insert attribute names.
"javascript.preferences.jsxAttributeCompletionStyle": "auto",
```

therefore, the default setting for `jsxAttributeCompletionStyle` is `auto` and by setting it to `"none"` in your `settings.json` file you overwrite that default setting.